# double free or corruption(out) - Alocação Dinâmica em C

Tags: c, matriz, alocação

Na disciplina de Estrutura de Dados na faculdade, como exercício, foi passado a implementação de um algoritmo que gere a matriz transposta de uma dada matriz alocada dinamicamente. Fiz a implementação e o algoritmo está funcionando corretamente, no entanto, quando o usuário insere na quantidade de linhas ou colunas, um valor acima de 3(4 para cima), ao final da execução do código, recebo a seguinte mensagem:
double free or corruption(out)

Pesquisei sobre o erro mas não achei o local no código em que estaria gerando essa mensagem.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** transposta( int m, int n, int** mat ){

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    int** matrizt = (int**)(malloc(n * sizeof(int)));

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        matrizt[ i ] = (int*)(malloc( m * sizeof(int)));

    for( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++)
            matrizt[ j ] [ i ] = mat[ i ] [ j ];

    return matrizt;

}

void imprime(int linhas, int colunas, int** matriz){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < linhas; i++ ){
        for( j = 0; j < colunas; j++ ){
            printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int linhas = 0,colunas = 0;

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    printf("Informe a quantidade de linhas: ");
    scanf("%d", &linhas);

    printf("Informe a quantidade de colunas: ");
    scanf("%d", &colunas);

    int **matriz = ( int** )( malloc( linhas * sizeof( int ) ) );

    for( i = 0; i < linhas; i++ )
        matriz[ i ] = ( int* )( malloc( colunas * sizeof( int ) ) );

    for( i = 0; i < linhas; i++ )
        for( j = 0; j < colunas; j++ )
            scanf( "%d", &matriz[ i ][ j ]);


    printf("Matriz digitada:\n");
    imprime(linhas,colunas,matriz);

    int **matrizt = transposta( linhas, colunas, matriz );

    printf("Matriz transposta:\n");
    imprime(colunas, linhas, matrizt);

    for(i = 0; i < linhas; i++)
        free(matriz[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < colunas; i++)
        free(matrizt[i]);

    free(matriz);
    free(matrizt);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é o seguinte:

```
int **matriz = ( int** )( malloc( linhas * sizeof( int ) ) );
```

Você teria de usar sizeof(int*) em vez de sizeof(int), pois está alocando uma matriz de matrizes, não uma matriz de inteiros.

Erro semelhante é cometido ao alocar matrizt.

É o tipo de erro que passaria despercebido numa arquitetura 32 bits (porque int tem o mesmo tamanho de um ponteiro) mas em 64 bits a maioria das arquiteturas manteve int com tamanho 32 bits.